# At-will Spellcasting in 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, spells

My gaming group is currently playing a game in 3.5e, but I have done some of the DnDnext playtests and find myself very intrigued by the wizard class' at-will cantrips, and I was wondering if there was a way to build a 3.5 character with at-will spells.  I've toyed around with some Sorcerer powers that increase spell slots, but I haven't come up with anything that truly allows for at-will spells.

Comment: You might want to look at Pathfinder, which is similar to 3.5. In that game, all classes with access to 0-level spells can cast them at will, though preparation-based spellcasters still have to choose which 0-level spells they have available on any given day. It was also a popular houserule for 3.5 among certain groups I played with before Pathfinder was developed.

Comment: That does sound like a pretty good house rule to throw in.  I can't see getting all our people to buy new rulebooks and learning a new system, but next time I DM I'll probably house rule that in.  Thanks!

Comment: Was it Complete Mage that had the feats that allowed spellcasters to perform certain spell-like abilities at-will so long as they had a particular (more powerful) spell prepared?

Comment: @GMJoe: There's also prestige classes for that, but they lave a limit of X/day, usually 1-3/day.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being able to actually cast an unlimited number of spells is--barring excessive shenanigans *via* things like using *plane shift* to go to planes wherein time passes at a far faster rate so you can rest in the middle of an encounter--impossible. Having a character with a host of at-will *spell-like abilities* is possible with some effort.

### Templates

If the character starts as a humanoid, he can take the templates half-fey (*Fiend Folio* 96) with at-will *charm person* for LA +2, half-rakshasa (*Dragon* #313 96) with at-will *empathy* (*Dragon* #313 94) for LA +3, and katane (*Dragon* #313 64) with at-will *spider climb* for LA +4, then top off with either half-celestial (*MM* 144) with at-will *daylight* for LA +4 or saint (*BE* 184) with at will *bless*, *guidance*, *resistance*, and *virtue* for LA +2. The character'll have 1 HD when he takes his 1st class level and count as a level 12 or level 14 character, but his ability scores will be *amazing.*

Also, this assumes reflavoring the names so the character isn't 3/2+ something.

### Races

Play a monster. All of the following monsters get at least a few spell-like abilities at will: the ECL 20 astra deva (*MM* 11) and trumpet archon (*MM* 17); the ECL 19 hezrou (*MM* 44); the ECL 18 vrock (*MM* 48); the ECL 16 couatl (*MM* 37) and erinyes (*MM* 54); the ECL 11 hound archon (*MM* 16); the ECL 12 succubus (*MM* 47); the ECL 10 drider (*MM* 89). You can probably tell where I stopped going through the *Monster Manual*, but picking a monster is almost always suboptimal to picking an actual non-LA, non-ECL character.

### Classes

The warlock from *Complete Arcane*'s been suggested, but I also recommend *Tome of Magic*'s binder, whose vestiges can grant spell-like abilities at will, like the Acererak vestige which grants at-will use of *detect undead* and *speak with dead*. The bound vestige persists for 24 hours after which it must be bound again, so it's not technically inherent-forever spell-like abilities. (Thus foiling your scheme to create a perpetual motion machine *via* an enslaved creature with an at-will spell-like ability.)

A 5th-level spellthief can steal another's at-will spell-like abilities all day long. The spellthief only gets one use of it before he must steal it again, but if the source is limitless so is the spellthief's ability to steal. Improved familiars make good targets.

### Feats

Other than *Complete Arcane*'s feat Innate Spell--which lets you trade *mind blank* or *polymorph any object* once per day for *mage hand* at will--getting at-will spell-like abilities *via* feats looks impossible.

However, like *everything* in *D&D 3.X*, being a caster and ruthlessly pushing the limits of the feat Craft Wondrous Item (*PH* 92-3) pretty much lets you *make* anything your DM allows. With the core rules setting a precedent with *hand of the mage* (*DMG* 258), convincing your DM to allow crafting other comparable at-will items should be trivial.

There's one feat, though, that I mention here because it's the Feats section: Fiendish Summoning Specialist (*PlH* 39). You needn't *take* it; just know it exists.

### Spells

Depending on the errata the campaign uses the spell *polymorph any object* might be used to just *become* a creature with spell-like abilities, but neither *magic jar* nor *shapechange* grants access to a creature's spell-like abilities.

What does explicitly grant access to a creature's spell-like abilities is the 5th-level Sor/Wiz spell *fiendform* (*SpC* 90). It reads, "[Y]ou can take the form of any fiendish creature, demon, or devil *that can be summoned* by a *summon monster* I, II, III, IV spell..." (emphasis mine). So if the Fiendish Summoning Specialist feat exists in the campaign, by a strict reading, *other* folks have added to the *summon monster* lists, and those can be accessed by anyone who casts *fiendform*. The *fiendform* spell only lasts 1 minute per caster level and has as an unpriced but weird material component, *and* you've to convince your DM that other people totally put the demon, devil, or fiendish creature you want to change into on their *summon monster* list *via* the Fiendish Summoning Specialist feat, but if those obstacles are overcome--and you don't mind that sick feeling you get after having *so much* cheese--, have fun with your demonic and devilish at-will spell-like abilities. If being such a creature all day is required the *fiendform* spell is a valid target for the Persistent Spell feat (*CAr* 81) and multiple ways exist to reduce what would otherwise be an 11th-level spell to something that can be cast pre-epic.

There is not, to my knowledge, an identical opposite *celestialform* spell.

Comment: +1 for binder, the only class that I'm still willing to play in 3.5

Comment: Wow, this is amazing.  Far more detailed than I expected!  Thank you!

Comment: Och, don't forget 'bout MoI book - some of the soulmelds are working exactly spell-like AND the character may just refuse to reshape 'em for his entire life. They're not as flavorfull as Binders, but still pretty neat 8)

Comment: I'm AFB, so I cannot double-check, but vestiges typically grant Su abilities; does Acererak really have an Su ability that grants Sp abilities? Not impossible, but seems weird.

Comment: @KRyan It doesn't; they're still Su. My bad. But I think it was close enough for this question (which asks more for at-will abilities than spell-likes, really) despite its technical inaccuracy.

Comment: Agreed, was just surprised to see that.

Answer (score 10):

Complete Mage has a set of feats that provide, as long as you have certain spells memorized, you can do at will magical tricks based on the spell memorized.  These feats relate to various keywords, such as fire, electricity, or teleportation.  For instance, if you take the fire related feat, you get the at will ability to conjure a burst of flame that does 1d6 damage per level of the highest level fire spell memorized.  For the electricity feat, it does 1d6 damage per level of the highest level electricity spell memorized.  May want to look into that.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, and welcome to the site! Please read the faq, and when you have 20+ reputation, feel free to join the chat!

Comment: Ah, forgot the Reserve feats. For the record, most of them aren't very good (or, the active effect isn't; the Caster Level bonus can definitely be), though Summon Elemental is awesome. Good addition.

Comment: Excellent! This is more along the lines of what I was looking for, though the Warlock looks good, too, KRyan.

Answer (score 8):

## *Complete Arcane* has the Warlock

The Warlock from *Complete Arcane* is basically the at-will version of the Sorcerer. You get a ray that deals damage sort of comparable to Sneak Attack (i.e. 1d6 every other level, except at high levels it slows down for no apparent reason), as well as a dozen “invocations,” which are at-will arcane spell-like abilities.

Ultimately, the Warlock was badly over-charged for the privilege of having things at will. Most of the invocations aren’t especially awesome to be able to do constantly (though the flight, invisibility, and teleportation ones are pretty sweet), and in combat actions are usually a much tighter limit than spells per day. And invocations are **much** weaker than spells, at the same class level. But you can still do some pretty neat things and it does make you pretty independent and reliable.

As a side-note, the Dragonfire Adept from *Dragon Magic* uses similar mechanics, though he’s less “magely,” and some other alternative magic systems (meldshaping, pact magic, truenaming) are at least sort-of at-will, though again they differ quite a bit from your typical mage.

Lastly, there is a grossly-overpriced feat that can allow high-level regular spellcasters to use a select, low-level spell at will. I cannot recommend it.

Comment: What is the name of that horrible, horrible feat?  :-)

Comment: @ilinamorato I believe it's Innate Spell; there are a couple of different printings of it (3.0 and 3.5). Both are badly overpriced.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't seen that one...but yeah, it looks like it costs a lot for the little bit it gives you.  And it isn't even really at-will spellcasting, just additional casting.  I shall take your recommendation, thank you.

Comment: Warlocks get some really good invocations - one allows him to never be caught flat-footed and the other good one is the infamous eldritch glaive. Not so mage-y but they deserve mentioning I think since they make up for the lack of other good things.

Comment: @Zachiel eldritch glaive?  i don't remember that from Complete Arcane.

Comment: @acolyte It's from *Dragon Magic*. Full-round action, make a melee touch attack that deals *eldritch blast* damage at 10 ft. range, plus an additional attack for any iteratives you may have for high BAB. The *glaive* also remains until your next turn so you can make AoOs with it. It's a Blast Shape, but you can still apply Eldritch Essences to it.

Comment: @KRyan ineresting.  when does Warlock gain bonus attacks from BAB?  I mean, unless you kit yourself out specifically to take advantage of that invocation, i don't see you hitting things all that easily or it really becoming super strong.

Comment: @acolyte Touch-attacks are dead-easy to make; a Warlock doesn't even particularly need much Strength to hit them. They do gain only medium BAB in-class, so the second attack is at 8th and the third at 15th. Careful prestige classing can improve that, though. I suggest if you wish to know more, though, you start your own question on the subject.

Comment: @KRyan oh, wait, i see the benefit.  instead of the massive range from eldritch spear, you're getting the ability to use any additional attacks you might have (though at a shorter range).

Answer (score 1):

I believe there was a add-on class called the "Hedge Wizard" which specialized in cantrips.  I would recommend looking into it.  Sadly, I do not have the pdf on hand, but it might be something worth looking into for you.

Comment: I believe the Hedge Wizard is in Power Classes. It's 3rd party if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

If your character has written scrolls for all known spells, you achieve the same effect: being able to cast any spell you know at will, without having to bend the rules and without having to be a special class.

But it costs XP and GP to do so; plus you need the Scribe Scroll feat.